# i am not able to figure it out how the .end function is working in this cpp program

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, maps

It is a map problem In which I am taking a string and an int input form the user and then simply printing out values corresponding to the keys and if the key entered by the user has no corresponding value or the key doesn't exist then I am printing out Not found Now the thing I am not able to understand is how if (name.find(s1)!=name.end() is working in the code given below  the whole code is written by me except the if block which I have mentioned so help me out to understand the working of the if statement

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,x,query;
string s,s1;
map<string,int> name;
map<string,int> ::iterator itr;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> s >> x;
    name[s]=x;
}
cin>>query;
for (int i = 0; i < query; i++)
{
    cin>>s1;
    if (name.find(s1)!=name.end())
    {
       cout<<s1<<"="<<name[s1]<<endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Not found"<<endl;
    }
    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end (2) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: From your code it results you understood it. I'm not sure on what you do not understand. `name.find(s1) == name.end()` means _"I reached the end and did not find `s1`"_. If you negate the condition - `!=` - you get the opposite: _"I found it"_.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of `iterators` and that containers hold items `[begin, end)`. The `end()` function returns an iterator to one item past the end of the container (so you have gone past the end). The `find()` function returns an iterator to the item you were looking for (if it exists) or one past the `end()` if it does not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end() function return an iterator that represent the end of a container, here a map. If the function find(s1) return an iterator that is equal to the iterator given by end(), then it means that it didn’t find s1.